# How to properly display deeper array values?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having trouble accessing the deeper part of an array with PHP and display it a certain way on the page.

Im trying to display data like this with a city and a count:

```
Mobile (3)
Auburn (2)
```

Here is my array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [city] => Mobile
                [numLocations] => 3
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [city] => Auburn
                [numLocations] => 2
            )

    )

)
```

Here is what I have so far. This just displays the word 'Array'.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $state = $row['state'];
    $stateAbv = $row['stateAbv'];
    $city = $row['city'];
    $numSLocations = $values['cnt']; 

    if (!isset($rows[$row['state']])){
        $rows[$row['state']] = array();
    }

    $rows[$row['state']][] = ['city' => $city, 'numLocations' => $numLocations];
}

foreach($rows as $state => $cities){
   echo array_column($cities, 'numLocations'));
}
```

Comment: Check out the manual, https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php array_column returns an array of values, but you also loose the key - you need to rethinkg your approach or maybe array_sum the array_col - I'm not totally sure what your endgame is

Comment: your code and that array do not match - `$rows[$row['state']][] = ['city' => $city, 'numLocations' => $numStores];` there are no keys in that array.

Comment: `$numSLocations = $values['cnt']; `  `$values` is undefined....

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to display data like this with a city and a count:
>
> Mobile (3)
>
> Auburn (2)

Untested

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    if (!isset($rows[$row['state']])) $rows[$row['state']] = 0; //initialize with 0

    $rows[$row['state']] += $row['cnt']; //increment the num Stores
}
```

Rows should be something like this:

```
['Mobile' => 3, 'Auburn' => 2]
```

You have this issue, too (**$values**):

```
$numSLocations = $values['cnt'];
```

In other words what is `$values`, without more context there is no way to know what that is. I'll just assume you meant `$row`

Then (if you literally want it with the () and the 2 line returns.)

```
foreach($rows as $state => $num){
   echo "$state ($num)\n\n";
}
```

Output

```
Mobile (3)

Auburn (2)
```

If your trying to convert that array, I have no idea how that is related to this (MySql results):

```
print_r(array_column($array[0], 'numLocations', 'city'));
```

This only works if `city` is unique and won't do increments.

> This just displays the word 'Array'.

Of course, because `array_column` returns an array (as I just showed above), and you cannot echo an Array, you can but it just will say "Array".  Which is exactly what it does in this code:

```
foreach($rows as $state => $cities){
   echo array_column($cities, 'numLocations')); //returns an array
}
```

So instead use `print_r` or `var_export` etc...  The result of the above would be something like:

```
 [0 => 3,1 => 2]
```

Which is basically this:

```
array_column($array[0], 'numLocations')
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

It feels like you have only first index, you can skip it by `array_shift`

```
$row = array_shift($row);
// now fetch both the data.
$temp = array_column('numLocations','city');
foreach($temp as $k => $v){
    $result[] = $k.'('.$v.')';
}
```

This should solve your problem.